# The use of Try and Catch

Tags: vb.net

I know this might be easy for some older andf more experienced VB.Net developers but me as a developer starting out a learning I wanted to know what "Try" and "Catch" is used for.

Comment: There are tons of help and tutorials on the subject: http://bit.ly/16U4nBP

Answer (score 2):

`try`, `catch`, `finally`, and `throw` are core to an Exception Handling framework, which is a way to communicate an "exceptional" condition in the code -- most notably errors.

If you are using libraries or frameworks, chances are they have a chance to throw an exception if something fails, and it is your code's responsibility to catch and handle that exception (logging, display to user, try to fix the condition and try again, etc.)

Example (in C#-ish pseudocode, but hopefully you'll get the gist:

```
try {
   doSomething();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   log("doSomething() failed: " + ex.getMessage() + " - " + ex.getStackTrace()); 
}
```

You'll see that the exception contains at least three types of useful information:

1. The type of exception it is.
2. The message contained in the exception
   (set by the code that threw the exception), and
3. The stack trace,
   which traces the call stack to the spot the module, line number, and
   error occurred.

Hope that starts you on your path to learning how to handle exceptions in your code.

Comment: Nicely written, but I would generally exit my routine if an exception occurs. Only logging the exception is generally not enough. In Java I would create a new, more generic exception for the specific method, with the old exception as cause...

Comment: I didn't really want to overwhelm the original poster with details ... if they're asking this very newbie question about try-catch I didn't think that they'd be ready for anything more detailed...

Comment: Yeah, that's always a bit of a tricky thing. On the one hand you want to keep it simple, on the other hand show best practices. I tend to go for the latter, but I can understand when somebody chooses the former (unless it is really bad practice...)

Answer (score 0):

It is used to catch any exceptions that are thrown. If any statement inside the `try` block throws an exception, the `catch` block is executed. If there is a `catch` block associated to the specific exception thrown, that block is executed. Here is the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) that goes into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

When any exception detected by .net in your try scope, it goes to catch scope, and then you can handle the problem in the catch